# tensorflow: After adding a rnn the whole work doesn't work

Tags: image, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, bidirectional

I have downloaded a code of FCN for image segmentation and it ran well. Now I want to add a rnn layer attempting to refine the result according to the work "ReSeg: A Recurrent Neural Network-Based Model for Semantic Segmentation". My code shows as follows:

This part is for the inference:

```
def inference(image, keep_prob):
    """
    Semantic segmentation network definition
    :param image: input image. Should have values in range 0-255
    :param keep_prob:
    :return:
    """
    print("setting up vgg initialized conv layers ...")
    #model_data = utils.get_model_data(FLAGS.model_dir, MODEL_URL)
    model_data = scipy.io.loadmat("H:/Deep Learning/FCN.tensorflow-master/imagenet-vgg-verydeep-19.mat")
    mean = model_data['normalization'][0][0][0]
    mean_pixel = np.mean(mean, axis=(0, 1))

    weights = np.squeeze(model_data['layers'])

    processed_image = utils.process_image(image, mean_pixel)

    with tf.variable_scope("inference"):
        image_net = vgg_net(weights, processed_image)
        conv_final_layer = image_net["conv5_3"]

        pool5 = utils.max_pool_2x2(conv_final_layer)

        W6 = utils.weight_variable([7, 7, 512, 4096], name="W6")
        b6 = utils.bias_variable([4096], name="b6")
        conv6 = utils.conv2d_basic(pool5, W6, b6)
        relu6 = tf.nn.relu(conv6, name="relu6")
        if FLAGS.debug:
            utils.add_activation_summary(relu6)
        relu_dropout6 = tf.nn.dropout(relu6, keep_prob=keep_prob)

        W7 = utils.weight_variable([1, 1, 4096, 4096], name="W7")
        b7 = utils.bias_variable([4096], name="b7")
        conv7 = utils.conv2d_basic(relu_dropout6, W7, b7)
        relu7 = tf.nn.relu(conv7, name="relu7")
        if FLAGS.debug:
            utils.add_activation_summary(relu7)
        relu_dropout7 = tf.nn.dropout(relu7, keep_prob=keep_prob)

        W8 = utils.weight_variable([1, 1, 4096, NUM_OF_CLASSESS], name="W8")
        b8 = utils.bias_variable([NUM_OF_CLASSESS], name="b8")
        conv8 = utils.conv2d_basic(relu_dropout7, W8, b8)
        # annotation_pred1 = tf.argmax(conv8, dimension=3, name="prediction1")

        # now to upscale to actual image size
        deconv_shape1 = image_net["pool4"].get_shape()
        W_t1 = utils.weight_variable([4, 4, deconv_shape1[3].value, NUM_OF_CLASSESS], name="W_t1")
        b_t1 = utils.bias_variable([deconv_shape1[3].value], name="b_t1")
        conv_t1 = utils.conv2d_transpose_strided(conv8, W_t1, b_t1, output_shape=tf.shape(image_net["pool4"]))
        #fuse_1 = tf.add(conv_t1, image_net["pool4"], name="fuse_1")

        deconv_shape2 = image_net["pool3"].get_shape()
        W_t2 = utils.weight_variable([4, 4, deconv_shape2[3].value, deconv_shape1[3].value], name="W_t2")
        b_t2 = utils.bias_variable([deconv_shape2[3].value], name="b_t2")
        conv_t2 = utils.conv2d_transpose_strided(conv_t1, W_t2, b_t2, output_shape=tf.shape(image_net["pool3"]))
        #fuse_2 = tf.add(conv_t2, image_net["pool3"], name="fuse_2")

        shape = tf.shape(image)
        deconv_shape3 = tf.stack([shape[0], shape[1], shape[2], NUM_OF_CLASSESS])
        W_t3 = utils.weight_variable([16, 16, NUM_OF_CLASSESS, deconv_shape2[3].value], name="W_t3")
        b_t3 = utils.bias_variable([NUM_OF_CLASSESS], name="b_t3")
        conv_t3 = utils.conv2d_transpose_strided(conv_t2, W_t3, b_t3, output_shape=deconv_shape3, stride=8)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////this is from where i added the rnn        
        shape_5 = tf.shape(image)
        W_a = 224
        H_a = 224
        p_size_a = NUM_OF_CLASSESS
       # x = tf.reshape(conv_t1, [shape_5[0],H_a,W_a, p_size_a])
        x = tf.transpose(conv_t3, perm=[0,2,1,3]) 
        x = tf.reshape(x,[-1,H_a,p_size_a])
        mat = tf.unstack(x, H_a, 1)
        lstm_fw_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_HIDDEN, forget_bias=1.0)
        lstm_bw_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_HIDDEN, forget_bias=1.0)
        #with tf.variable_scope('rnn1_1'):
        try:
            outputs, _, _ = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, mat,
                                                dtype=tf.float32,scope='rnn1_1')
        except Exception: # Old TensorFlow version only returns outputs not states
            outputs = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, mat,
                                        dtype=tf.float32)        
        outputs1 = tf.reshape(outputs,[H_a, shape_5[0], W_a, 2 * N_HIDDEN])
        outputs1 = tf.transpose(outputs1,(1,0,2,3))
        x_1 = tf.reshape(outputs1,[-1,W_a,2 * N_HIDDEN])
        mat_1 = tf.unstack(x_1, W_a, 1)
        lstm_lw_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_HIDDEN, forget_bias=1.0)
        lstm_rw_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_HIDDEN, forget_bias=1.0)
        #with tf.variable_scope('rnn1_2'):
        try:
            outputs2, _, _ = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_lw_cell, lstm_rw_cell, mat_1,
                                              dtype=tf.float32,scope = 'rnn1_2')
        except Exception: # Old TensorFlow version only returns outputs not states
            outputs2 = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_lw_cell, lstm_rw_cell, mat_1,
                                        dtype=tf.float32)           
        outputs2 = tf.reshape(outputs,[W_a, shape_5[0], H_a, 2 * N_HIDDEN])
        outputs2 = tf.transpose(outputs2,(1,2,0,3))
///////////////////////////////////////////////////till here
        annotation_pred = tf.argmax(outputs2, dimension=3, name="prediction")

    return tf.expand_dims(annotation_pred, dim=3), outputs2
```

and this part is for the training:

```
def train(loss_val, var_list):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate)
    grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss_val, var_list=var_list)
    if FLAGS.debug:
        # print(len(var_list))
        for grad, var in grads:
            utils.add_gradient_summary(grad, var)
    return optimizer.apply_gradients(grads)


def main(argv=None):
    keep_probability = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_probabilty")
    image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3], name="input_image")
    annotation = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1], name="annotation")

    pred_annotation, logits = inference(image, keep_probability)
    tf.summary.image("input_image", image, max_outputs=2)
    tf.summary.image("ground_truth", tf.cast(annotation, tf.uint8), max_outputs=2)
    tf.summary.image("pred_annotation", tf.cast(pred_annotation, tf.uint8), max_outputs=2)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean((tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,
                                                                          labels=tf.squeeze(annotation, squeeze_dims=[3]),
                                                                          name="entropy")))
    tf.summary.scalar("entropy", loss)

    trainable_var = tf.trainable_variables()
    if FLAGS.debug:
        for var in trainable_var:
            utils.add_to_regularization_and_summary(var)
    train_op = train(loss, trainable_var)

    print("Setting up summary op...")
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

    print("Setting up image reader...")
    train_records, valid_records = scene_parsing.read_dataset(FLAGS.data_dir)
    print(len(train_records))
    print(len(valid_records))

    print("Setting up dataset reader")
    image_options = {'resize': True, 'resize_size': IMAGE_SIZE}
    if FLAGS.mode == 'train':
        train_dataset_reader = dataset.BatchDatset(train_records, image_options)
    validation_dataset_reader = dataset.BatchDatset(valid_records, image_options)

    sess = tf.Session()

    print("Setting up Saver...")
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.logs_dir, sess.graph)

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.logs_dir)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        print("Model restored...")

    if FLAGS.mode == "train":
        for itr in xrange(MAX_ITERATION):
            train_images, train_annotations = train_dataset_reader.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
            feed_dict = {image: train_images, annotation: train_annotations, keep_probability: 0.85}

            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)

            if itr % 10 == 0:
                train_loss, summary_str = sess.run([loss, summary_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                print("Step: %d, Train_loss:%g" % (itr, train_loss))
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, itr)

            if itr % 500 == 0:
                valid_images, valid_annotations = validation_dataset_reader.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
                valid_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={image: valid_images, annotation: valid_annotations,
                                                       keep_probability: 1.0})
                print("%s ---> Validation_loss: %g" % (datetime.datetime.now(), valid_loss))
                saver.save(sess, FLAGS.logs_dir + "model.ckpt", itr)

    elif FLAGS.mode == "visualize":
        valid_images, valid_annotations = validation_dataset_reader.get_random_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
        pred = sess.run(pred_annotation, feed_dict={image: valid_images, annotation: valid_annotations,
                                                    keep_probability: 1.0})
        valid_annotations = np.squeeze(valid_annotations, axis=3)
        pred = np.squeeze(pred, axis=3)

        for itr in range(FLAGS.batch_size):
            utils.save_image(valid_images[itr].astype(np.uint8), FLAGS.logs_dir, name="inp_" + str(5+itr))
            utils.save_image(valid_annotations[itr].astype(np.uint8), FLAGS.logs_dir, name="gt_" + str(5+itr))
            utils.save_image(pred[itr].astype(np.uint8), FLAGS.logs_dir, name="pred_" + str(5+itr))
            print("Saved image: %d" % itr)
```

The error was described as:
    Not found: Key inference/rnn1_2/fw/basic_lstm_cell/weights not found in checkpoint

So i think there must be something wrong with the variables.
I'll be very appreciate if someone could tell me how to fix it!
looking forward to your help!

Comment: Are you restoring from an old checkpoint (e.g. left behind in `FLAGS.log_dir` from before adding the RNN to your model)? Try switching to a different (empty) `FLAGS.log_dir` and running again.

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem solved!